# Tab Indexing is circulating in datagridview rows not moving to next control in windows form, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabindex

If tab index is on last row and column of datagridview, if I press tab key at this point, it is moving to the first row and column of datagridview instead of next control(button). Can someone suggest me how to stop the tab indexing on last row and move to next control. I tried this code.

```
private void dgCoreRoutes_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
   {
     if (dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell.RowIndex == dgCoreRoutes.Rows.Count-1)
     {
         dgCoreRoutes.TabStop = true;
     }
     if (dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell.ReadOnly)
     {
        dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell = GetCoreRoutesGridNextCell(dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell);
        e.Handled = true;
     }
}

private DataGridViewCell GetCoreRoutesGridNextCell(DataGridViewCell currentCell)
{
     int i = 0;
     DataGridViewCell nextCell = currentCell;
     do
     {
       int nextCellIndex = (nextCell.ColumnIndex + 1) % dgCoreRoutes.ColumnCount;
       int nextRowIndex = nextCellIndex == 0 ? (nextCell.RowIndex + 1) % dgCoreRoutes.RowCount : nextCell.RowIndex;
       nextCell = dgCoreRoutes.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[nextCellIndex];
       i++;
     } 
     while (i < dgCoreRoutes.RowCount * dgCoreRoutes.ColumnCount && nextCell.ReadOnly);
     return nextCell;
}
```

Comment: Hard to guess what might happen, DGV already has special handling for the Tab key and does this at keydown, not keyup.  If you want to do this correctly you must derive your own class from DGV and override the [ProcessTabKey() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,6725d687ff64c319).  This usually turns out poorly btw.

Comment: I want to set tab index on specific columns that has editing controls, maybe this method is an issue, i am trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned false and set focus to next control, now its working for me.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   if(keyData == Keys.Tab && dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell == dgCoreRoutes.Rows[dgCoreRoutes.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[(int)enGridColumns.Margin])
   {
     btnNext.Focus(); 
     return false;
   }
   else if (keyData == Keys.Tab && dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell.ReadOnly)
   {
     dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell = GetCoreRoutesGridNextCell(dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell);
     return true;
   }
   else
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as invested, when you edit a cell in the dataGridView, there maybe another control for your editing, so we could not get the Tab key event in KeyUp or keydown method.

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
 {
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab && dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell.RowIndex == dgCoreRoutes.Rows.Count-1)
    {
       dgCoreRoutes.TabStop = true;
       //return true;
       //Use standardTab = true; if you want to tab only standard columns and not cells.
    }


else if (keyData == Keys.Tab && dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell.ReadOnly)
{
       dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell = GetCoreRoutesGridNextCell(dgCoreRoutes.CurrentCell);
       e.Handled = true;
       return true;
}
     else
           return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Okay so you mean, i should remove those events, and try to handle this functionality using this ProcessCmdKey overridden method

Comment: yes, dont remove. just redirect your handle here and comment your existing handler for a while and see how this works out for you.

Comment: Yes its not going to first row but getting freeze, not going anywhere, i tried to set next control focus property but that didn't help, trying other options

Comment: I think it is freezing because of 'TabStop = true'. remove that line of code.

Comment: Let me try and be back with a solution

Comment: Thank you for your help @CodeBrain i have made some changes now its working fine.